# Vertical alignment of subfigures with different subcaptions length

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

I would like to vertically align 3 subfigures (same size), but I don't manage to do so if the subcaptions have different lengths, like here:

[image]

This is the code that generated the image:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{3D printed wax mould post processing}
\label{fig:Mould}
\begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldWithSupport}
    \caption{Just after removal from the 3D printer plate}
    \label{fig:MouldWithSupport}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldAfterWashing}
    \caption{After removal of support wax and ultrasonic cleaning}
    \label{fig:MouldAfterWashing}       
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t!]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldAfterSilanization}
    \caption{After silanization}
    \label{fig:MouldAfterSilanization}      
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't write `t!`. The `!` is used with float specifiers, but in this case the optional argument has to do with where to 'anchor' the subfigure. Remove all the `!` and the subfigures are top-aligned.

Alternatively, as mentioned by Axel Sommerfeldt in the comments, you could use `\subcaptionbox`, which automatically aligns the first lines of the subcaptions. By default, this will place the subcaptions on the same side of the figures as the main caption (in this case, above). To have the subcaption on the bottom, you can load `subcaption` with the option `position=b`, or use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}`.

In the code below I added the `\captionsetup` line within the second `figure` environment, which makes the setting local to that `figure`. By adding it to the preamble (or using `\usepackage[position=b]{subcaption}`) the setting is global.

Finally, I also added `\hfill` between the `subfigure`s/`subcaptionbox`es to space them out on the line. With your code, there was a normal interword space between them.

(The `demo` option to `graphicx` replaces all images with black rectangles.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{3D printed wax mould post processing}
\label{fig:Mould}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldWithSupport}
    \caption{Just after removal from the 3D printer plate}
    \label{fig:MouldWithSupport}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldAfterWashing}
    \caption{After removal of support wax and ultrasonic cleaning}
    \label{fig:MouldAfterWashing}       
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldAfterSilanization}
    \caption{After silanization}
    \label{fig:MouldAfterSilanization}      
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}
\centering
\caption{3D printed wax mould post processing}
\label{fig:Mould}
\subcaptionbox{Just after removal from the 3D printer plate\label{fig:MouldWithSupport}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldWithSupport}}
\subcaptionbox{After removal of support wax and ultrasonic cleaning \label{fig:MouldAfterWashing}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldAfterWashing}}
\subcaptionbox{After silanization \label{fig:MouldAfterSilanization}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{./Experimental/MouldAfterSilanization}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As an alternative one can use `\subcaptionbox` (instead of `subfigure` environment) to get sub-figures which are horizontally aligned on the very first caption line.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks. How would you place the subcaptions below when the main caption is above (as in this case)? It seems the default for `\subcaptionbox` is to have the subcaptions on the same side of the figures as the main caption.

Comment: Either load `subcaption` with option `position=b`: `\usepackage[position=b]{subcaption}`, or use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}` after loading the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 7):

You could just insert `\newline` to the shorter caption. Worked for me, the other solutions looked too complicated :)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! This answer needs more details. Thats a comment.  [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)